# How can i force checking in documents - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow

How can i force documents to check in after upload?
It seems some users can't just get it.I have mandatory field which they cant save docs until fields are filled.But it seems to me they don't even read the warning saying the documents haven't been checked in .
I reckon they just click cancel and then the document remains checked out to them.

Any idea what are ways to force check in? Workflow maybe

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Education.

If your user training does not change their behaviour, you need to go up the food chain.

Talk to the users' manager(s). Explain how their employees' behaviour impacts negatively on the performance/efficiency/effectiveness of the process/business.

Run a quick analysis on how much it costs the business to carry the behaviour of these users. Take into account time wasted on support calls, troubleshooting, lost productivity of co-workers who cannot do their work because of files not checked in.

Temporarily remove the users' permissions to add files to the library. Give them another training session before giving them access again. Remove permissions again if they don't learn.

Comment: +1, completely agree with you @teylyn.

Comment: Thanks teylyn.I know thats the way and i agree but...
So im thinking of putting in an event handler to fire and force check in.Any thaughts

Comment: +1 for "temporarily remove permissions until they retake training".